# LINQ to JSON - Select Individual properties belong to a navigational property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following query, where Nodes is a navigational property inside of MonProfiles.

```
var nodes = await dbContext.MonProfiles.Include(x => x.Nodes).
            Where(x => x.Id == profileId).
            Select(x => x.Nodes.
                Select(y => new { y.NodeNativeId, y.NodeClassId, y.NodeName, y.NodeClass.ClassName })).
                ToListAsync();

return Json(new { nodes });
```

The problem I am facing is that the returned JSON in an array within an array:

```
{
    "nodes": [[{
        "NodeNativeId": 1234567,
        "NodeClassId": 9999,
        "NodeName": "TestName",
        "ClassName": "TestClassName"
    }]]
}
```

What I would like to return is:

```
{
    "nodes": [{
        "NodeNativeId": 1234567,
        "NodeClassId": 9999,
        "NodeName": "TestName",
        "ClassName": "TestClassName"
    }]
}
```

This is my first time using LINQ to only select individual properties that belong to the Navagation Property, and this first time I have encountered this type of a result due to this.  How can I correct my LINQ query so that I have the JSON output I expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try select many instead

```
var nodes = await dbContext.MonProfiles.Include(x => x.Nodes).
        Where(x => x.Id == profileId).
        SelectMany(x => x.Nodes.
            Select(y => new { y.NodeNativeId, y.NodeClassId, y.NodeName, y.NodeClass.ClassName })).
            ToListAsync();
```

This effectively flattens a list of a list

Comment: Would that be on the first select, the second, or both?

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  I will approve the answer in once I am allowed (9 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

It should also work with

```
return Json(nodes);
```

instead of

```
return Json(new { nodes });
```

I'm writing from the phone so I haven't tested it.